# Prob. 8, Sec. 16 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: What topology is inherited by a straight line as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_l\times\mathbb{R}$ and ...?

Tags: general-topology

Here is Prob. 8, Sec. 16 in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> If $L$ is a straight line in the plane, describe the topology $L$ inherits as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}$ and as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}_l$. In each case it is a familiar topology.

My Effort:

> The topology of $\mathbb{R}_l$ has as a basis all half open intervals $$[a, b) \colon= \left\{ \ x \in \mathbb{R} \ \colon \ a \leq x < b \ \right\},$$
>   where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers such that $a < b$.
>
> And, the topology of $\mathbb{R}$ has as a basis all open intervals $$(a, b) \colon= \left\{ \ x \in \mathbb{R} \ \colon \ a < x < b \ \right\},$$
>   where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers such that $a < b$.
>
> So the topology of $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}$ has as a basis all the Cartesian products $$ [a, b) \times (c, d) = \left\{ \ x \times y \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \ \colon \ a \leq x < b, \ c < y < d \ \right\}, \tag{A}$$
>   where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are real numbers such that $a < b$ and $c < d$.
>
> And, the topology of $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}_l$ has as a basis all the Cartesian products $$ [a, b) \times [c, d) = \left\{ \ x \times y \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \ \colon \ a \leq x < b, \ c \leq y < d \ \right\}, \tag{B} $$
>   where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are real numbers such that $a < b$ and $c < d$.
>
> Thus the toplogy that $L$ inherits as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}$ has as a basis all the intersections $$ L \cap \left(  [a, b) \times (c, d) \right) = \left\{ \ x \times y \in L  \ \colon \ a \leq x < b, \ c < y < d \ \right\}, \tag{1} $$
>   where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are real numbers such that $a < b$ and $c < d$.
>
> And, the toplogy that $L$ inherits as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}_l$ has as a basis all the intersections $$ L \cap \left(  [a, b) \times [c, d) \right) = \left\{ \ x \times y \in L \ \colon \ a \leq x < b, \ c \leq y < d \ \right\}, \tag{2}$$
>   where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are real numbers such that $a < b$ and $c < d$.

Is what I've stated so far correct? If so, then what next? Do we need to consider separately the cases when (i) $L$ is vertical and (ii) $L$ has a finite slope?

P.S.:

After reading the comments:

Munkres has not discussed homeomorphisms so far in the book; so I'd like to avoid the concept.

> If $$L = \left\{ \ x \times y \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \ \colon \ x = p \ \right\},$$
>   where $p$ is a given real number, then from (1) we can conclude that the topology that $L$ inherits as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}$ has as a basis all sets of the form 
>   $$ \left\{ \ p \times y \ \colon \ y \in \mathbb{R}, \ c < y < d \ \right\} = \left\{ p \right\} \times (c, d),$$
>   where $c$ and $d$ are real numbers such that $c < d$. And, this basis has a one-to-one correspondence with the basis for the topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

Is this sufficient to conclude that the topology inherited by $L$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}$ is the same as the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$?

> And, from (2), we can conclude that the topology $L$ inherits as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}_l$ has as a basis all sets of the form 
>   $$ \left\{ \ p \times y \ \colon \ y \in \mathbb{R}, \ c \leq y < d \ \right\} = \left\{ p \right\} \times [c, d),$$
>   where $c$ and $d$ are real numbers such that $c < d$. And, this basis has a one-to-one correspondence with the basis for the topology of $\mathbb{R}_l$.

Is this sufficient to conclude that the topology inherited by $L$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}_l$ is the same as the topology of $\mathbb{R}_l$?

> If $$ L = \left\{ \ x \times p \ \colon \ x \in \mathbb{R} \ \right\},$$
>   where $p$ is a given real number, then the topology that $L$ inherits as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}$ has as a basis all sets of the form 
>   $$ \left\{ \ x \times p \ \colon \ a \leq x < b \ \right\} = [a, b) \times \left\{ p \right\}, $$
>   where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers such that $a < b$. And, this basis has a one-to-one correspondence with the basis for the topology of $\mathbb{R}_l$.
>
> And, the topology that $L$ inherits as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}_l$ has as a basis all sets of the form 
>   $$ \left\{ \ x \times p \ \colon \ a \leq x < b \ \right\} = [a, b) \times \left\{ p \right\}, $$
>   where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers such that $a < b$. And, this basis has a one-to-one correspondence with the basis for the topology of $\mathbb{R}_l$.

Now what if 
$$ L = \left\{ \ x \times y \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \ \colon \ y = px + q \ \right\},$$
where $p$ and $q$ are some given real numbers such that $p \neq 0$? How to tackle this case?

P.S.:

> The subspace topology inherited by the straight line $L$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}$ has as a basis all the intersections
>   $$ L \cap \left( [a, b) \times (c, d) \right) = \{ \ x\times y \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \ \colon \ a \leq x < b, c < y < d, y = px+q \ \} , $$
>   where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are any real numbers such that $a < b$ and $c < d$. Note that our $p$ and $q$ are fixed.
>
> For the sake of definiteness, let us put $p \colon = 2$ and $q \colon= 1$. So our straight line is 
>   $$ L = \{ \ x \times y \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \ \colon \ y = 2x + 1 \ \}. $$
>
> Now consider the rectangle $$ [ -1, 1) \times (-2, 1) = \{ \ x \times y \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \ \colon \ -1 \leq x < 1, -2 < y < 1 \ \}. $$
>   The intersection of this rectangle rectangle with our straight line $L$ is 
>   $$L \cap \left( [-1, 1) \times (-2, 2) \right) = \{ \ x \times y \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \ \colon \ -1 \leq  x < 0, -1 \leq y < 1, y = 2x+1 \ \}.  $$

Comment: As an aside, you may find the following site helpful: https://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-2/section-20-the-metric-topology/problem-3-solution/ It provides solutions to these problems, though it may not be so instructive as seeking help with your own solution

Comment: Yes, in both of the problems, the slope of the line makes a difference.

Comment: In the first problem, if $L$ is vertical the topology is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, and if $L$ is not vertical then the topology is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R_l.$ Consider, geometrically, all  the different kinds of intersections a member of the base for $\mathbb R_l\times \mathbb R$ can have with $L.$

Comment: @Muno I've just added some content to my post. So can you please take a look now?

Comment: @WilliamElliot based on your comment, I've added some more detail to my post. Can you please check it once again?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet please oblige me by reading through my edited post; I've included some more stuff based on the above comments.

Comment: For the case of  a horizontal line you should write $L=\mathbb R\times \{p\},$ not $\{x\times p\}.$ Your work for the vertical and horizontal lines is correct...... The case of all non-vertical lines can be done all together: If the line is not vertical,  consider that $$ L \cap ([a,b)\times (c,d) )=[ L\cap ((a,b)\times (c,d))]\cup [L \cap (\{a\}\times (c,d))],$$ if not empty, is either $ \{x,(Ax+B): x\in (e,f)\}.$ (with $e<f$),.... or ....$ \{(x,Ax+B):x\in [a,f)\}$ with $a<f$. It may help to draw some pictures of rectangles and lines.

Comment: here im  sir..,......